# get previous collection values from Doctrine2 events

Tags: events, collections, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to detect entity previous collection values from Doctrine2 events?

In EventSubscriber, I can get previous entity values from `getEntityChangeSet()` but `getScheduledCollectionUpdates()` always return current collection after modifications

For example:

```
function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

    $uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
    $changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
    $collectionUpdates = $uow->getScheduledCollectionUpdates();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `postPersist` event is fired after your changes were persisted to the database, so obviously there will no longer be any changes scheduled after persisting (so on `postPersist` this will be empty).

You should use `prePersist` event if you want to catch scheduled/pending updates.